# Conditional nosetests from bash

Tags: bash, jenkins, nose

I'm attempting to only run tests in files that have changed between git commits as part of our integration testing in Jenkins.

The code below works, *unless* the filters remove all file results.  Then ALL tests get run by nose.  I would want no tests run in that case.

```
if [ $GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT != $GIT_COMMIT ]; then
    git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d $GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT $GIT_COMMIT | grep .py | xargs nosetests -vv
fi
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: You code shouldn't work at all; the condition in your `if` statement should be `test "$GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT" != "$GIT_COMMIT"` or something equivalent.

Comment: You are completely right.  I tried to simplify the snippet for easier reading, and instead wrote broken code!  Fixing...

Comment: The `x` prefix is unnecessary; it's an old hack to accommodate old, buggy versions of `[`. Modern versions of `[` don't need it, let alone `[[`.

Comment: Good to know.  I thought it was necessary in case the variable came back empty since I didn't wrap in quotes.

Comment: `[[` doesn't perform word-splitting or pathname expansion on parameter expansions, so the quotes aren't necessary. With `[`, the right thing to do is to quote the expansions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've got it.  Needed to split the initial results and check if the list is empty before calling nosetests.

```
if [ $GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT != $GIT_COMMIT ]; then
    TESTFILES=$(git diff --name-only --diff-filter=d $GIT_PREVIOUS_SUCCESSFUL_COMMIT $GIT_COMMIT | grep .py)
    if [ -z "$TESTFILES" ]; then
        echo "No test files found"
    else
        nosetests -vv $TESTFILES
    fi
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't test this way. Its too error prone.

First, I think you should [mark your tests](http://nose.readthedocs.io/en/latest/plugins/skip.html) so you can skip them appropriately
Then, in your Jenkins build you can selectively pick and choose what you want to run. If you have hundreds or thousands of tests which take a long time you should consider paralleling the tests with pytest-xdist. As you probably already know, all tests should run independent.

My philosophy is test everything or don't bother.

Comment: No, I wouldn't test this way exclusively.  I'm slightly abusing python's unittest to run functional grey-box system tests.  This is part of a script to run the most unstable tests where the test code has changed BEFORE running all the tests in integration.

Comment: I see. For grey-box testing take a look at RobotFramework. It does wonders. Sorry, don't know much about the original question.